# No more error on React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I'm doing a typo, React-Native doesn't throw an error anymore.

For example, if I have this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getData();
}

getMyData() {
  // Something
}
```

Note the name of the function is different. React-Native doesn't complain about this anymore but it was before.

I might have overridden something by mistake, but I have no idea where to look at.

Does any of you know how the errors are caught?

Thanks

Comment: did you check your scheme in xcode if you are building for release or not? If you  are using an offline bundle, it won't throw an error when changing the code.

Comment: could you show all file code?